# TrelloNet objects always returning null

Tags: c#, trello, trello.net

```
ITrello trello = new Trello(AppKey);
trello.Authorize(Token);
Member me = trello.Members.Me();
```

for example, in this case it was to return my user but always return null, i want to know how to fix it. Thaks.

Comment: have you debugged this?

Comment: yes, but i don't understand, seems like everything is right, but it don't work...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing the correct AppKey `string` to the `Trello` constructor?

Per the documentation, you have to do it like so.

```
ITrello trello = new Trello("[your application key]");
```

Where `[your application key]` is the key string you get from https://trello.com/1/appKey/generate (need to be logged in to Trello before you access that url.

The token in your 2nd line is also a string, not a class.

```
trello.Authorize("[the token the user got]");
```

Source: [Trello.net Wiki](https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/wiki)

Comment: yes, i used this a lot, but somethimes it just don't work, i don't know why, but the key and the token are right.

Comment: You need to provide your full code then. From what you have posted, difficult for us to help you. I was able to access the end points in your situation by loggin in to trello and accessing the end points in this page: https://trello.com/app-key